# How to diff the redirection of two commands in a shell script

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

in the command line I can diff the output of two commands with

```
$ diff <(cmd1) <(cmd2)
```

but if I put this in a shell script

```
$ sh do_two_comands_diff.sh
```

It does not work

```
$ diff <(ls) <(ls -a)
0a1,2
> .
> ..

$ cat > test_diff.sh
diff <(ls) <(ls -a)
^D

$ sh test_diff.sh
test_diff.sh:1: test_diff.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I tried to use $() instead () with no success. I know that inside the shell things sometimes need to be done in a different way that in the console but here I don't have a clue. Could someone be so kind to point me to the right links to learn how to do this things properly inside a shell and why this happens?

P.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be sure to use the same interpreter on your script that you are using on the command line by prepending

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: silly me! I was calling it with sh and forgot that <() is a bash!! thanks

Comment: you were so fast you need to wait 11 minutes to have your deserved 'question answered' tick ;-)